# SSRS Excel Export, Chart image shown compacted

Tags: reporting-services, charts, export-to-excel

Some days ago I had to modify a SSRS Report in order to add another group. That Report contains a Chart which before this change was properly shown, but now, In the Web Report Viewer It looks ok.

[image]

But when exporting to Excel (xls), The Chart looks like to be compacted:

[image]

And the user has to expand at least the groups that are aligned with the chart in order to see It well.

[image]

I tried to create a Subreport with only the chart embedded, also tried to put the chart inside a rectangle but none of those solutions worked.

In Excel there is a property for the images to indicate not moving nor sizing with cells and It does the trick but I cannot see the property in the Chart stuff.

Do you know how to have the graph displayed properly without having to expand the groups?

I'm working with SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Just put a rectangle on your report then cut the chart, click in the rectangle and paste it in. That will stop it trying to align with the table.

It's important that you don't just drag the chart onto the rectangle. You must cut and paste it in.